# Memory structure for an array of pointers to objects (visualization)

Tags: c++

I can visualize the situation when, for example, I have allocated memory in the following way:

```
Position* arr1 = new Position[5];
```

Position being a class in my program that describes a positional point with x and y values.

There would be a pointer on the stack that points to the first element (a Position object) of the array "arr1" on the heap so it would look something like this:

[image]

How would it look if I were to create an array of pointers though? For example:

```
Position** arr2 = new Position* [2];

arr[0] = new Position(3, 7); // Constructs a point with x and y values.
arr[1] = new Position(9,6);
```

Where are all the pointers and objects stored in the memory in my second example? Are there pointers on the stack that point to pointers on the heap which then point to the objects on the heap or something?

Also, if I were to `delete [] arr2;`, where would the objects remain in the memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one automatic variable, `arr2` pointer object. The rest is on the free store. If you only `delete[] arr2`, you'll free the memory for the pointers, and not the objects they point to.

```
arr2 ---+  +---------------------------------+
        |  |                                 |
        |  |                                 |
        +----> [Position*, Position*]        |
           |       |          |              |
           |       |          +----> [9, 6]  |
           |       v                         |
           |    [3, 7]                       |
           +---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can I ask how do you make this frame in ascii?

Answer (score 3):

1. Every object created by `new` is on the heap. So in your example, the array of two pointers would be on the heap. `arr2`, as a local variable, would be on the stack.
2. The `Position` objects, being separately allocated by `new`, are in their own separate heap blocks. They need to be `delete`d individually. Otherwise, they remain on the heap. An object cannot move between the stack and heap. (Although C++11 provides `std::move`, this is really a special kind of ownership transfer; it does not magically turn a heap address into a stack address.)
3. `delete [] arr2` would leave the objects in memory. As the array of pointers does not own the referenced objects, this code does not ask to destroy the indirectly referenced objects.

You should always avoid using `new` and `delete` directly in favor of container objects (`std::vector` or `std::array` would work here), or smart pointers such as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer of the array arr2 will be on the stack. The other pointers arr2[0], arr2[1] etc will be on heap and these pointers will point to different locations on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram would have an extra level of indirection. So replace `myArray` with `arr2`, having `arr2[0]` and `arr2[1]`. Then, still on the heap, draw another arrow from `arr2[0]` to a `Position value`, and from `arr2[1]` to another `Position` value.

If you used `delete[] arr2`, these values would remain at whatever position in memory they were assigned originally.

Comment: You are suggesting a change to his design. His diagram does match his code (the first example).

Comment: I was pointing out how you would modify it to represent the 2nd example.